# How to specify warnings on anchor links?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Is there a standard way to mark anchor links with aria-like attributes to specify (non-rendered) warnings? i imagine something like:

```
<a href="nudes.html" aria-warning="nsfw">Article #1: Blue things</a>
<a href="flashes.html" aria-warning="epilepsy">Article #2: Red stuff</a>
```

The use case is a multi-page magazine website, where i would like to allow users with some unknown dedicated reader software to be notified about potentially problematic content/style behind the links, but without affecting the normally displayed content on the linking page.

Comment: *"without affecting the normally displayed content on the linking page"*.  If you don't change the visual text, how will a user know about the warning?  ARIA attributes are hints for screen reader users (and other assistive technology users) but don't help sighted users.

Comment: i am interested to know if there is a standard interface to communicate such meta data to specialized agents that may take them into consideration. while i am not interested in changing my design and notifying regular users, i still want to allow users with special needs which use dedicated assistive software or browser modes to avoid these links if that functionality is part of their software solution

Comment: The definition of accessibility is providing information to some users but not other users. So with you trying to provide information to assistive technology users (which I applaud you for), you are actually creating an accessibility issue because the metadata you want to provide is not available to all users.

Comment: That being said, you could provide additional details for assistive technology through the [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#aria-label) property. Just make sure the visible text of your link is also contained in the aria-label so that you don’t cause a [WCAG 2.5.3 issue](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG22/#label-in-name)

Comment: You could also try [`aria-roledescription`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#aria-roledescription) but it’s a newer attribute so I’m not sure how well supported it is among the various browsers and screen readers.

Comment: thanks! as they say that [No ARIA is better than Bad ARIA](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/read-me-first/), and considering, as commented above, that the scope may be wider than that related to accessibility (eg NSFW), i am inclined to use the global HTML attribute [itemprop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/itemprop) which seems to be used for a similar functionality of adding metadata. In my case the anchor element will get `itemprop="flashing"`

Comment: great minds! it seems that there is a suggested [standard](https://schema.org/accessibilityHazard):  <meta itemprop="accessibilityHazard" content="flashing"/>

Comment: ...and i am making the assumption that AT software will understand that the hazard relates to the linked page and not to the hyperlink itself.

Comment: they also have content warnings. see discussion here: https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/discussions/3385

Comment: `itemprop` and schemas are not read by screen readers so that won't help

Comment: I would say the silliness of the last example demonstrates the accessibility issue here. Why would you expose a “flashing content” warning _only_ to screen reader users?

Comment: @Andy I am just looking for a (semi-)standard way to communicate (read: expose) warnings as metadata. regular users should not be affected by these warning (maybe they will get some global warning beforehand), but interested parties would be allowed to take warnings into consideration at their responsibility.

Comment: I would say the most relevant standard for metadata is schema.org, but currently it’s not supported by AT as far as I know, especially not screen readers. But using schema.org information along with W3C’s suggested vocabulary would be the way to go, if you want to start using it already, maybe along with `visually-hidden` classes. It still doesn’t make any sense to hide it from anybody not using AT.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the accessible name of the link in order to communicate this information. This can achieved using the `aria-label` attribute. Make sure that the visible label is always included though, since this attribute completely overrides the accessible name that existed from the contents of the anchor element. For example:

```
<a href="nudes.html" aria-label="nsfw">Article #1: Blue things</a>
```

**However, be cautious of this approach entirely**.

The more inclusive approach would be to make this information available to everyone. What you are doing goes against inclusive design principles of equitable use, since the content is different for someone who is visually impaired. Users will miss information, and if information is only available for a particular set of users, is it important enough in the first place?

To make it more inclusive, add the additional info in text that is visible to everyone. For example:

```
<a href="nudes.html">Article #1: Blue things <span class="tag">NSFW</a>
```